# failed to iterate through journal: bad message

Tags: systemd

I received the following error trying to view logs on an embedded ARM board running Angstrom Linux with systemd.

```
# journalctl -f    
Failed to iterate through journal: Bad message
```

I searched the systemd documentation and didn't find any useful reference to this message or what to do to resolve it.

The filesystem is on an sdcard, so it's possible that it's caused by file corruption, although the system displays no other signs of this. Going in to /var/log/journal and removing all the files in there fixed the problem. This has got logging working again at the cost of losing all my previous log message.

What can be the underlying cause of this?

Comment: Is your disk full?

Comment: no, it isn't full

Comment: Any sign of disk errors in syslog? Will it pass a SMART check?

Comment: No sign of filesystem errors, it's on an SD card so SMART is impossible.

Comment: Buggered if I know.

Comment: Oh, and -1 for not using a search engine, and for not including relevant details.

Comment: This question shows zero effort on your part -- Google. Research. Tell us what you've done to try to debug this. We should not have to pull teeth to get adequate troubleshooting information.  See [this meta question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) for some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [bug](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=779449#c6) in your version of systemd that has since been fixed upstream.

Comment: Clicking this link today in 2023 results in message "You are not authorized to access bug #779449. To see this bug, you must first log in to an account with the appropriate permissions. "